# Data Import errors for skus NOT in store

Tags: magento-1.9, import, data

We have an inventory CSV file (with the fields: SKU, available_inventory, incoming_available) that we upload DAILY. It has 6,800 SKUs, but 600+ are are not in the store, so they generate an error when imported, and if the number of errors exceed 100, the import cannot take place [image: see attached screenshot of errors]. I need to find a plugin or some code that permits a data import even if there are more than 100 errors. NOTE: We do not want to add those additional SKUs to the store, so that is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Migrate your import process to MAGMI which is an external PHP based mass import system.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/

You can run the import from the command line or create a cronjob to perform the import from your CSV data file i.e.

```
php /path/to/magmi/magmi.cli.php -profile=PROFILENAME -mode=update -CSV:filename="/path/to/csv/MAGE_Import.csv"
```

Comment: Thx for your response. A Cron job would normally be the best route, but our CSV must always be modified a bit before importing.  I was able to resolve this by increasing the error limit hardcoded in the following class:

app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Abstract.php
on the following line:

protected $_errorsLimit = 100;    (increased the limit from 100 to 1200)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by increasing the error limit which is hardcoded in the following class:

app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Abstract.php
on the following line:

protected $_errorsLimit = 100;    (increased the limit from 100 to 1200)